# Phase portrait of a $3\times 3$ matrix

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

Seeing other years' exams, I found an exercise that we never did before (yes, in an exam, the perfect moment to test our creativity).

It's the following:

> Consider the linear system $$x'=\begin{bmatrix} -2&1&3 \\ -1&-2&1 \\ 0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}x$$
>
> Give a fundamental matrix to this system, **and explain the phase portrait.**

I know how to find the fundamental matrix with the exponential matrix or with the eigenvalues and eigenvectors directly, but I don't know how to do the phase portrait of a $3\times 3$ system. We've never did that before.

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: I've explained phase portraits with $2\times 2$ matrices, but never with $3 \times 3$

Comment: Don’t you mean $x'$ on the left-hand side?

Comment: Yes, edited, sorry.